# How could I retrieve all the relationships from a (spring-data-)neo4j database?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-graph

Is there a way to simply retrieve all relationships of a certain type - where type is a `@RelationshipEntity` annotated class - from a spring-data-neo4j [SDN] database? (working with 2.0.0.RC1 & embedded DB)

When I try the method provided by SDN :

```
relationShipRepository.findAll()
```

it gives me the following error:

`org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: __type__ property not found for RelationshipImpl #9672 of type 7 between Node[4844] and Node[4875].`

Full stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/j2gqcjxh (though looking

A solution would be to use the low level (neo4j) API (namely `GraphDatabaseService` ) to retreive all nodes, and then for each node retreive all their relationships and verify if their `__type__` field matches the type of relationship I'm interested in. But then why provide `findAll` method for relationships?

Simple explanation is that the the advised interface is the same for nodes and relationships - but does any documentation say that we are not allowed to use `findAll` for relationships?

Or: examining the relationship entity in the db, it contradicts the exception, because **type** is defined correctly as expected and it is possible to retreive the relationship through highlevel (SDN) API once you retrieved the node and you call `getRelationship*(..)`

On other note: does anyone know if `ImpermanentDataGraph` service will be included in v 2+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the relationships that are created as Relationship-entities in SDN or *all* relationships?

What is your use-case?

Relationship-Entites are also added to the index. 
Is the relationship 9672 a relationship-entity?

For the Relationship-Repository - that depends  on the TypeRepresentationStrategy, if the "indexed-strategy" is used, Relationship-Enties are also available in their respective repository (but not globally).

In Neo4j 1.6.M01 there is a new `[GlobalGraphOperations][1]` class that also has `getAllRelationships()`.

`ImpermanentGraphDatabase` is out of the Neo4j-testing toolchain. And it will stay there (and improve in performance) in v2+.

Comment: Yes, 9672 is a `RelationshipEntity` created by `relateTo` used in as `RelClass rel = nodeEntity.relateTo(otherNodeEntity, RelClass.class, RELATIONSHIP_NAME);`. RelClass is annotated with `@RelationshipEntity`. In some parts of the app I retrieve from a field annotated with `@RelatedToVia`. Still, I am not able to retrieve it using the corresponding repo's `findAll` method.

Comment: If the problem still persists, could you raise an issue (with a test-case showing this) at http://spring.neo4j.org/issues ?

Comment: The problem is not present anymore (1.6M02). Thank you for your assistance (and sorry for not getting back to you). And if I find suspicious behavior, proven by a testcase I will post it there. Currently I've met no such issues.